# Laravel form request: how to avoid n+1 queries when validating arrays?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to know the best approach when validating arrays of a lot elements.

For example,

```
    <?php
   
    namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class UsersRolesAssignmentRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        public function rules(Request $request)
        {
            return [
                'roles' => 'array|min:1',
                'roles.*.role_id' => 'required|exists:roles',
                'roles.*.user_id' => 'required|exists:users'
            ];
        }
    }
```

The problem here is if i have 100 elements i will need to touch the database 200 times.

Comment: how about you just do a whereIn() to the models and do an array_diff of user inputs and whereIn query results?

Comment: In that way i will not be able to show the correct error message.

Comment: you might be, you can send a custom error message for inputs just like a validator does. and you can find the non-existing ids in array diff

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's checking against the DB 200 times, that seems like a pretty large oversight. But, if it is, you can use the `in()` rule, along with some pre-fetched results instead:

```php
public function rules(Request $request){
  $roleIds = Role::pluck('id')->implode(',');
  $userIds = User::pluck('id')->implode(',');
  return [
    'roles' => 'array|min:1',
    'roles.*.role_id' => "required|in:{$roleIds}",
    'roles.*.user_id' => "required|in:{$userIds}"
  ];
}
```

Just don't forget to import your Models via `use App\Models\User;` and `use App\Models\Role` (or whatever path your Models are at).

This rule will generate the following:

```
'roles.*.role_id' => 'required|in:1,2,3,4,5', // ... 
'roles.*.user_id' => 'required|in:1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: i am not sure either,  i have tried your solution already but i think in large scale databases this will cause some issues. Thanks for your anwer!

Comment: You can double check via `DB::enableQueryLog()` before and `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` after your validation is done. This will show the queries that were run, including the `exists` check. If 200+ queries are run, then it's an N+1 oversight, but if only a handful were run, then you're good. And yes, this approach will likely have some performance issues for large databases.

Comment: I've tested and indeed the n+1 issue exists.